# Wrapping additional parameters to variadic parameter pack in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Based on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422625/c11-thread-wrapper-with-parameter-forwarding), I am writing a small class to help me distribute work to a bunch of threads. While constructing the thread I would like to pass a loop counter as an additional parameter to the parameter pack to be used as a thread_id. Is this possible?

`qthread.h`:

```
#ifndef QTHREAD_H
#define QTHREAD_H

#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

class qthread
{
    std::vector <std::shared_ptr <std::thread>> threads;
public:
    // Constructor
    template <class Fn, class... Args>
    qthread(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args)
    {
        size_t maxNumThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < maxNumThreads; i++)
        {
            // While constructing the thread I would like to also pass i as a thread_id to the function in the parameter packing
            threads.push_back(std::make_shared <std::thread>(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }
    }
    // Destructor
    ~qthread()
    {
        for(auto thr_p:threads)
        {
            thr_p->join();
        }
    }
};

#endif /* QTHREAD_H */
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "qthread.h"

void test(const size_t thread_id, int x)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        x += i;
    }
    std::cout << "thread: " << thread_id << ", total: " << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    qthread(test, 5); // Distribute the 'test' task to n threads -- note that this doesn't work in this case since the function requires two parameters
}
```

Comment: You really don't want to forward rvalue arguments *multiple times*. They'll get moved from the first time.

Comment: What would suggest doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) in the comments, there is [a `std::thread` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) with the following signature:

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

This constructor will call copy/move the function `f` and the arguments `args...` to its thread-accessible storage, then call `f(args...)` in the new thread.

It is sufficient to use...

```
threads.push_back(
    std::make_shared <std::thread>(
        std::forward<Fn>(fn), thread_id, std::forward<Args>(args)...
    )
)
```

...to bind `thread_id` as an argument of `fn`.

This will result in a function call similar to:

```
fn(thread_id, args...);
```

---

**In general**, if you want to bind some arguments to a function and obtain a new callable object that will wrap the previous one, you want to use a lambda or a `struct`.

C++14 example *(assuming the thread id is the first argument)*:

```
threads.push_back(
    std::make_shared <std::thread>(
        [thread_id, &fn](auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto)
        { 
            // "Bind" `_thread_id` as first argument of `fn`.
            return std::forward<Fn>(fn)(thread_id, 
                std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); 
        }, 
        std::forward<Args>(args)...
    )
);
```

---

C++11 example *(assuming the thread id is the first argument)*:

```
template<typename TF>
struct bind_thread_id
{
    TF _fn;
    int _thread_id;

    bind_thread_id(TF fn, int thread_id) 
        : _fn(fn), _thread_id(thread_id) 
    { 
    }

    template<typename... Ts>
    auto operator()(Ts&&... xs) 
    {
        // "Bind" `_thread_id` as first argument of `fn`.
        fn(_thread_id, std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);   
    }
};

// ...

threads.push_back(
    std::make_shared <std::thread>(
        bind_thread_id<Fn>{fn, thread_id}, 
        std::forward<Args>(args)...
    )
);
```

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with `threads.push_back(std::make_shared <std::thread>(std::forward<Fn>(fn), thread_id, std::forward<Args>(args)...));`?

Comment: @T.C. I think he wants to call `fn` with `args...` **and** `thread_id` - at least, that's how I interpreted the question. Like `fn(thread_id, args...)` or `fn(args..., thread_id)`.

Comment: ...and just sticking `thread_id` in the argument list of `std::thread`'s constructor won't do that because...?

Comment: @T.C. Since the std::thread constructor expects two arguments the constructor you suggested doesn't work. I originally had the same thought!

Comment: @ruser45381 What crazy `std::thread` implementation are you using?

Comment: Whoops, @T.C. is correct - the [`std::thread` (3) constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) does call the function with the passed variadic arguments. His solution should work properly.

Comment: I'm using mingw-64 on Windows 7 64-bit. If I try to add the thread_id directly to the argument list I get the error: "Wrong number of arguments for function" (in a huge heaping mess of template errors)

Comment: I just tried to compile this in g++ 5.2.1 and clang++ 3.6 (using libc++) in Ubuntu 15.10 and I get the same error as above. Note that when I mentioned thread_id previously I actually meant the loop counter. I'm just being consistent with the other comments.

Comment: @ruser45381: could you please paste your compile log and your test code somewhere *(like pastie or pastebin)* and share it with us? A minimal example on an online compiler *(like godbolt, ideone or coliru)* would be even better.

Comment: https://ideone.com/hZ405g here's a minimal example with an online compiler (note that I'm using ideone c++14 compiler but it's the same error). Same error on godbolt using c++11 as well: https://goo.gl/LCyh03

Comment: @ruser45381: well - it obviously doesn't compile because `test` requires two parameters: `void test(const size_t thread_id, int x)`. Calling `qthread(test, 5)` doesn't pass any argument to `test`'s `x` parameter. Calling `qthread(test, 5, 1)` sets `thread_id = 5` and `x = 1` in the `test` function call, so it compiles properly. The number of passed arguments **needs** to match `test`'s arity. Also, the reported `error: static_assert failed "Wrong number of arguments for function"` is pretty self-explanatory and not a *"huge heaping mess of template errors"* in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Calling `qthread(test, 5)` _should_ pass the correct arguments to `test`: `i`, the loop counter (for `thread_id`, the first argument) and `5`, the `x` value (the second argument), no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98828/discussion-between-ruser45381-and-vittorio-romeo).